# How to create login page in vaadin framework with db connectivity?

Tags: java, vaadin

Im have just started to work with vaadin framework. I have created a login page with vaadin's default login page. Can anyone tell me how to check the username and password with the database and move to next page on successful login. Im using psql and connected using hibernate.

Regards
Suresh S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done the login page and session handling using threadlocal pattern in Vaadin framework and it is working fine. Refer [Login Form](http://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Authenticating%20Vaadin-based%20applications?p_r_p_185834411_title=Authenticating%20Vaadin-based%20applications) Sessions [Threadlocal pattern](http://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/ThreadLocal%20Pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Even though it uses JPA and the appfoundation framework, the Login Screen implementation of http://code.google.com/p/instant-webapp/ might give you some inspiration on how this can be achieved.

Comment: i have added the login screen somehow and it is working now. But im struggling to get the user details stored in the session variables. o you know how to access the vaadin session variables.

Comment: I need to display the name of the user through out the application's header area. So I need to take the name from session. But can you tell how to store or take values from session in vaadin framework.